# Inequality of functions solving Riccati ordinary differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I consider two real valued ordinary differential equations with coefficients $\alpha>0$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\gamma >0$, given by
$$
y'(t)=\alpha + \beta y(t) - \gamma y(t)^2
$$
for $t >0$ and $y(0)=\delta >0$ and
$$
f'(t) = \alpha + \beta f(t)
$$
for $t >0$ and $f(0)=\delta >0$. I want to show that $y(t) \leq f(t)$ for all $t \geq 0$. How do I show this when there is no general explicit solution for the Riccati differential equation for $y$?

Answer (score 0):

We have $y(0) = f(0) = \delta > 0$.

Then $$y'(0) = \alpha + \beta y(0) - \gamma y(0)^2 \leq \alpha + \beta y(0) \leq \alpha + \beta f(0)$$
This follows directly from the equations given.  I literally did nothing but plug in $t=0$.

So the slope of $y$ is less than the slope of $f$ at $0$.  This implies that $y \leq f$ in an interval to the right of $0$.  Take an $x = c>0$ within that interval.  Now
$$y'(c) = \alpha + \beta y(c) - \gamma y(c)^2 \leq \alpha + \beta y(c) \leq \alpha + \beta f(c)$$

So $y$ is less than $f$, and is increasing more slowly than $f$ is.  So $y$ remains less than $f$ on some interval $(c,c+h)$.  Take a point $k$ in that interval.
Repeat the argument.

Comment: Hi @RobertTheTuror, can I ask you to be a bit more precise? What do you mean by evaluating the derivatives at $t=0$. The derivatives are not defined here. Is it in terms of limits of $t$? And What do you mean by "repeat the argument"? Best, J. Goles

Comment: Your iterated interval $[0,c_1:=c],[c_1,c_2:=k],\cdots$ argument may not hold. If the length of each interval shrinks exponentially; that is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}c_n<\infty$ then we know nothing about the behaviour of $y$ in the interval $\left[\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}c_n,+\infty\right)$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Good point. I haven't figured out how to plug that hole yet.  Probably remainder theorem for Taylor polynomials?